# Add edit buffer alias to vim with directory mapping

Tags: backbone.js, vim, vi, vim-plugin

I want to add a custom mapping of VIM's edit buffer command but with a default directory mapping.

Here is an example:

I have a directory called javascript/backbone. Every time I want to access a file in this folder, I have to type the entire path. I want to do something like this:

`:Ebackbone models/xyz.js.coffee`

Can someone tell me how to go about this in my .vimrc? Here is my present VIM config in case: https://github.com/shikhar-j/.vim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the simplest case, that would be:

```
command! -nargs=1 Ebackbone javascript/backbone/<args>
```

If your current working directory can change, you may have to use `:execute` and prefix `expand('%:p:h')` to get the current file's path.

Also, command completion would be nice; you can achieve that with a custom completion (`:help :command-complete`) and `glob()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have nothing against plugins, [Tim Pope](https://github.com/tpope/)'s [Projectionist plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-projectionist) can help you achieve that.

To use this plugin, you add a `.projections.json` file to the root of project containing:

```
{
  "models/*.js.coffee": {
    "type": "backbone"
  }
}
```

This will allow you to run the command `Ebackbone` and having it tab-complete with every file that matches the glob `models/*.js.coffee`.